# Memory is never released when opening pandas data frame in ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

Here is a very simple example of the code I'm working with...

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import pandas


if __name__ == "__main__":

    def i_use_lots_of_memory():
        print 'doing something that uses a lot of memory'
        data = pandas.read_csv('large_txt_file.txt')
        del data
        # do other things here as soon as I've solved mem usage issues
        print 'ha ha  I used up a ton of memory.'

    def simplest_callback_ever(future):
        _ = future.result()
        print 'callback was run'


    class ManagesFileReading(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=24)

        def add_job(self, callback=None):
            future = self.pool.submit(i_use_lots_of_memory)
            if callback:
                future.add_done_callback(callback)


    mfr = ManagesFileReading()
    mfr.add_job(simplest_callback_ever)
```

In this example I'm opening a 800MB text file, which takes up about 2GB of memory.  The output is...

```
doing something that uses a lot of memory
ha ha  I used up a ton of memory.
callback function was run. Task is complete.
```

So the task completes, the problem is the memory is never released.  Even though the future has completed it never releases the memory.  The only way I can release it is to close the process pool by running self._pool.shutdown()

Unless I'm misunderstanding how ProcessPoolExecutor works, when the callback function is done that means the task was completed, right?  Why isn't the future being deleted and the memory being released?  Any ideas?